# Old value of global JS object changes when updated

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a global Javascript object for which I set some values and push to an array. Once I push it to my array and update its values, it changes the already pushed values in the array.
For example:

```
let obj1 = {"name":"", "age":""} //Assume this is declared outside the scope of the below block

{
    obj1.name = "john";
    obj1.age = 21;
    arr1.push(obj1);

    console.log(arr1) // [{name:"john", age:21}]
    
    obj1.name = "mary"; //Object in array has already changed here
    console.log(arr1) // [{name:"mary", age:21}]
    obj1.age = 24;

    arr1.push(obj1)
 
}
```

I want to understand why this happens and how I can avoid it from happening. I want to be able to push 2 different objects with different values to the array. Is the only way to do this by creating another object?

Comment: because it is the same object. You are pushing a reference to the object. You are not making a copy of it each time you push.

Comment: *"I want to be able to push 2 different objects with different values to the array. Is the only way to do this by creating another object?"* - It sounds like you answered your own question right there.  Consider the semantics of what you just stated... If I want to have two objects, do I need to create two objects?  Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to understand why this happens

You created an object. You pushed it into an array. You modifed that object. You pushed it into the array again.

> Is the only way to do this by creating another object?

Yes. If you want two different objects, then you have to create two different objects.